# Java Refection : NoSuchMethodException on high load

Tags: java, reflection

I am getting below exception ONLY when high load is running like 25 calls (same scenario) per second and it is not coming for every call, it is coming for few times only.However, when I run few calls at a time i am not getting this exception. I checked that method public execute method exists in com.abc.block.Rules class and this is the reason exception is not coming when i run few calls.

> 02 Oct 2019 02:00:01,021 [Worker[23]] ERROR [SNode] 80]
>   NoSuchMethodException during reflective call on class
>   com.abc.block.Rules java.lang.NoSuchMethodException:
>   com.abc.block.Rules.execute(com.abc.common.cdata)     at
>   java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:1786)

While running load reflection is not working correctly. Any inputs please ?

Code :

```
    Object port = service.getClass()
            .getMethod(xmlSNode.getPortMethodName()).invoke(service);

    outResult  = port
                 .getClass()
                 .getMethod(xmlSNode.getOperation().getName(),
                         inputs.getInputTypes())
                 .invoke(port, data);
```

Rule call :

```
public Object[] execute(cdata c) throws Exception{
...
}
```

Any input please

Comment: This *could* be a race condition, most likely in *your* code. Is it possible that `port` sometimes doesn't have the expected type for a short time, or that you're accessing some data in a non-threadsafe way (like having a `static` field that shouldn't be static?)? Those kinds of mistakes often don't show up under light load, as the concurrent access is far enough apart by time, but under heavy load, it might come to light.

Comment: Thanks for your input. Can you suggest how to debug and resolve this ?

Comment: @VJS try looking into synchronization, locking and Java concurrency (in general): https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html